# CultureInfo.Name Property

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo

Reading from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.name(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **CultureInfo.Name Property**
>   Gets the culture name in the format *languagecode2-country/regioncode2.*

Then the example:

```
 Console.Write("{0,-7}", ci.Name);
 [...]

/*
This code produces the following output.  This output has been cropped for brevity.

CULTURE ISO ISO WIN DISPLAYNAME                              ENGLISHNAME
ar      [...]
bg      [...]
ca      [...]
zh-Hans [...]                    
cs      [...]
da      da  [...]
de      de  [...]
el      el  [...]
en      en  eng ENU English                                  English                                 
es      es  spa ESP Spanish                                  Spanish                                 
fi      fi  [...]
zh      zh  [...]
zh-Hant zh  [...]                   
zh-CHS  zh  [...] 
zh-CHT  zh  [...] 

*/
```

Could someone explain the *two* letter `languagecode2-country/regioncode2` format, and how to get the "`en-US`" string from the `CultureInfo` ?

Say, I have the following code:

```
var culture = Context.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>().RequestCulture.UICulture;
string lang2 = culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.ToLower();
string lang4 = culture.Name.ToLower();
```

finally `lang2 == lang4`, is there a way to get the "correct" `lang4`?

More than that, the CultureInfo does not check the invalid culture names, any combination of two letter can work ([fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f04qoW)):

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {

        Console.Write(new CultureInfo("xx").Name);  // "xx" 
        Console.Write(new CultureInfo("xx-YY").Name);   // "xx-YY"  
    }
}
```

Comment: `new CultureInfo("en-US").Name` should do the trick. If it returns 'en' its the general English culture, not the specific United States one.

Comment: please see updated OP I explain better the problem.

Comment: I don't really understand why do you propose me to obtain "en-US" if you suppose I already have this string...

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/cultureinfo.cs,a99dfd86b8014a4a

Comment: @Serge I was indirectly saying that if the culture is region specific it would include that part if you access the `.Name` property. Apparently a request has been made that does not supply region (such as 'en-US'), so it falls back to the neutral ('en') culture. Why should it be 'en-US' when it can be 'en-GB' as well?

Comment: @Serge: I'm very confused... If your culture is en-US then .Name will return "en-US". If its only returning "en" then the culture is not "en-US" so why would you want code to return that?

Comment: I am also confused, the documentation says should return 4 letters name...

Comment: What do you mean by the "correct" lang4? Are you asking why  culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.ToLower() and culture.Name.ToLower() are different?

Comment: rather why the documented `format languagecode2-country/regioncode2` became `en`... I mean, the documentation should probably be updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example provided by MSDN returns only the *languagecode2* because it iterates over `CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.NeutralCultures)`. As the name implies, the `CultureInfo` being iterated are the **neutral** ones, so their name only consists of the two-letter lowercase language code.

More generally, a `CultureInfo` provides information about a specific culture. When it is not a neutral one.

If your code returns `en`, then it simply means a neutral culture was passed to it. If/when you pass it a specific culture (e.g.: en-US), then the name will match accordingly.

---

A lot more information can be gathered from the remarks section of the `CultureInfo` [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5):

`A neutral culture is specified by only the two-letter lowercase language code. For example, fr specifies the neutral culture for French, and de specifies the neutral culture for German.`

Comment: Thanks. The MS documentation page does not mention that information. I mean, "..culture is specified by" that doesn't explicitly mean saying about the "Name" property

Comment: Yes, the documentation is a bit unclear about that, especially if you look at the `Name` property documentation. Nonetheless, the main documentation of the `CultureInfo` class seems to be the one that is more complete, and the one to be trusted.

Comment: I actually just sent a feedback on the `Name` documentation page asking for it to be clearer for Neutral cultures.

Comment: I updated the OP with some details... it seems that CultureInfo does not check the valid cultures when it creates the class... by eg. `new CultureInfo("xx-YY")`

Comment: It is actually more complicated than that. When you create a `CultureInfo`, it delegates to your underlying OS. Before Windows 10, attempting to create an invalid culture was throwing a `CultureNotFoundException`. Since Windows 10, it seems the OS says any culture is correct (if it doesn't really exist, I believe it will have the data of the InvariantCulture). More information about that here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1669.

Comment: but say Windows 10 is on the dev machine... how about server machines or even Unix/Linux ones (Mono users...), say the fiddle i use: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RO37Js , the OS is Win10 (Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0)

Comment: @yorah Thanks for the last comment! I'm actually testing if one system supports a certain culture just by trying in a try-catch block. Reading your comment, I think this will break in some systems. Do you have any workaround for this? Checking if it's the invariant culture will be enough?

Comment: Maybe I could get all the available culture names ahead of time, and check if it's there! :)